# Last non empty value in mdx for events filtering between two dates and status

Tags: mdx

I have events in progress. Each event has a date, amount and status. I need a calculate member which return the last amount by event, state and between the first day in January until a selected date in the same year

I tried semiadditive LastChildNonEmpty but returns only one row for the event which has the last date

With these data I expect:

---

### | Events |  Date   | Amount | Status |

### | Event1 | 20180301 | 05 | open |

### | Event1 | 20180311 | 12 | open |

### | Event2 | 20180406 | 02 | open |

### | Event1 | 20180523 | 60 | close |

### | Event2 | 20180809 | 07 | close |

### | Event1 | 20190104 | 27 | open |

**Questions & Results**

*- Events between 20180101 and 20180331 status open:*
EVENT1 20180311 12  open

*- Events between 20180101 and 20180430 status open*
EVENT1  20180311    12  open

EVENT2  20180406    2   open

*- Events between 20180101 and 20180531 status open*
EVENT2  20180406    2   open

*- Events between 20180101 and 20180531 status close*
EVENT1  20180523    60  close

I'm sorry if the format is bad but I have reading and I don't know how to create a table with data

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the above problem with a calculated measure. The mdx function BottomCount will solve your issue. Here is a sample based on AdventureWorks. The below query list the Date, Sales reson and customer count.

```
select [Measures].[Customer Count] on columns,
nonempty(
{(
{[Date].[Date].&[20130101]:[Date].[Date].&[20130713]},
[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason])}
,[Measures].[Customer Count]
)
on rows
from [Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013])
```

Result 
[image]

Now lets make the calculated measure and test if for a sample case.

```
with member measures.t 
as 
(bottomcount(
nonempty(
existing
{([Date].[Date].[Date].members,[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].currentmember)}
,[Measures].[Customer Count]),
1
).item(0)
,[Measures].[Customer Count])

select measures.t on columns 
from [Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Date].&[20130101]:[Date].[Date].&[20130111],
[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Other])
```

[image]

The idea is that you can pass date range and the sales reason in where and the measure will list the last value.

Edit: The below query will handle situation when the user passes one date and attribute hierarchy is passed. If User hierarchy is passed the hardcoding of year start can be prevented

```
with member measures.t 
as 
(bottomcount(
nonempty(
{({[Date].[Date].&[20130101]:[Date].[Date].currentmember},[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].currentmember)}
,[Measures].[Customer Count]),
1
).item(0)
,[Measures].[Customer Count])
select measures.t on columns 
from [Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Date].&[20130111],
[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Other])
```

Comment: Thank you very much MoazRub, I'm going to test it.

Is posible use only one date in where clause and add the range in the measure?

Thanks again

Comment: @Luis you are welcome. If it helps then you might consider marking it as answer. As for the date range in the measure, I am not sure i understand what  exactly you mean by that. Can you provide a sample

Comment: I was testing your solution, but I need use only one date. I have written the range in the existing clause and only one date in where clause because my users only use one date. With my change doesn't run. I show you the query in the next comment because this is too long

Comment: with 
member measures.t 
as 
(bottomcount(
nonempty(
existing
{(
([Date].[Calendar].currentmember.parent.firstsibling.firstchild:[Date].[Calendar].currentmember)
,[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].currentmember)}
,[Measures].[Internet Tax Amount] ),
1
).item(0)
,[Measures].[Internet Tax Amount] )
select measures.t on columns,
nonempty(
[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason]
) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20130713])

Comment: Yes it works but with two dates. I need use only one date. Thanks @MoazRub